# StatusLabel - how to reset, or allow status text to time out or fade away

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a tabbed form with a StatusStrip at the bottom, which includes a StatusLabel.  I want to use this status label for various actions ("1 record updated" etc).  It is simple enough to create specific events to set the label's text property.

But how best to reset the status to blank?  The user could perform any number of other operations where the status is no longer meaningful (going to another tab, clicking other buttons etc.).

It is not feasible to create all the possible events to reset the status message.  Is there a way to incorporate some type of timer so that the message fades out after several seconds?  Has anyone else found a good solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes a timer would work for this to clear it.  Here is an example of one I've knocked together.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private System.Timers.Timer _systemTimer = null;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _systemTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(500); 
        _systemTimer.Elapsed += _systemTimer_Elapsed;
    }

    void _systemTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = string.Empty;
        _systemTimer.Stop(); // stop it if you don't want it repeating 
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "random text just as an example";
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _systemTimer.Start();

    }
}
```

Assume button1 is your action to update the status, and button2 is just a random way to start the timer (this can be however you want to start it, I've only used another button click as an example).  After the set amount of time passes the status label will be cleared.

Answer (score 4):

Is it truly important to clear the status though?  There are plenty of products which will keep their status label unchanged until the next status event occurs.  Visual Studio is a good example of this.  It may be worth simplifying your scenario and taking this approach.

If you do want to clear the status after an event I think the most maintainable way to do this is with a `Timer`.  Essentially clear after a few seconds when the status is set

```
Timer m_timer;

void SetStatus(string text) {
  m_statusLabel.Text = text; 
  m_timer.Reset();
}

void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  m_statusLabel.Text = "";
  m_timer.Stop();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response!  I did implement a timer; however I marked MattR's answer as accepted only because he gave a more complete example.

Comment: This answer stopped me from implementing something to clear my displayed label. I was on the fence. Cheers!